# Max Score then Offset Left one column

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying to find the max score and then offset left to find the name of the person that scored. However, the link below only allows for one column and one row at a time.

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/472213-offset-formula-using-max-determine-reference-cell-location.html

This is not what I need. I need to have an equation that allows me to find the max score and then offset that to the left by one and take the name. I will need it for multiple columns and rows in the same equation that can be easy to read. I have come across equations like this.

ADDRESS(MAX((A154:H174=MAX(A154:H174))*ROW(154:174)),MAX((A154:H174)*COLUMN(A:H)))

Sorry for not having a picture I don't have enough reputation. It was a screenshot of my spreadsheet. Thanks for any help that you can provide.

I am open to suggestions and edits on this post. I do desire to improve and use this more often.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming your data is names in A1:A9 and the score in B1:B9

```
=INDEX(A1:A9,MATCH(MAX(B1:B9),B1:B9,0))
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I have a graph spanning multiple columns. Would I need to have multiple equations for each column? I have seen similar answers to this and it did not work with what I was trying. So I will have a score in column b then another score in column d and I am trying to encompass both in the same equation.